# Custom Runtime exception not printing the stack trace

Tags: java, exception, stack-trace

Sorry for this very basic question, but I am stuck with this and m not able to  find a solution.

I have a Core Java application (Java version is 1.6). From my application I am calling a method in a jar, which is throwing a custom runtime exception.

I am not catching this exception, but still JVM is not printing the stack trace.

Does JVM by default will not print the stack trace, when a runtime exception is thrown and not caught? 
Or am I missing something which I can check?

Thanks in advance.

-Sandeep

Comment: Check the method inside the jar. You can use a java decompiler if you don't have source code inside the jar.

Comment: I have access to the code of jar, and even it does not catch any exceptions. It is only throwing runtime exception when certain condition is met.

Comment: Please show us the code.

Comment: It's possible to subclass Exception(String message,..., boolean writableStackTrace), i.e.,  whether or not the stack trace should be writable.

Comment: And I've just checked: catching and calling printStackTrace doesn't work, and getStackTrace gives you nothing. - If you have the code, you can see how the custom exception is defined, whether my assumption is correct. `class Custom extends Exception {
    public Custom( String msg ){
 super( msg, null, false, **false** );
    }
}` -- The last **false** is the one.

Comment: Below is the code in my application,
`Class MyApp{
executeQuery{
return Client.executeRequest(par1, par2, par3);
}
}`

And below code is from the jar which has Client class, 
`class Client{
executeRequest(String par1, String par2, String par3){
log.error(errResp);
throw new CustomException (errResp);
}`


`CustomException extends RuntimeException`

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, JRE should print a stacktrace of an uncaught exception. But you can always do it yourself:

```
try {
  someObject.someMethod();
} catch (Throwable t) {
  t.printStackTrace();
  throw t;
}
```

Comment: You mean writableStackTrace set to false, as in a comment to the question? In that case, it's true.